How to calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=x_1,Y=y_1)$ for dependent random variables?
If talking (only) about events $A,B$, then we know that $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$.
If $A,B$ are not independent, then one can use
$\mathbb{P}(A \cup B)=\mathbb{P}(A)+\mathbb{P}(B)-\mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ to calculate the possibility that $A$ and $B$ both occure.
If we have (discrete) random variables $X,Y$ how do we calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=x_1,Y=y_1)$?
(I know that if both random variables are independent, then its just the product of the single probabilities.)

"Given a random variable, what is its distribution?" This question cannot be answered without much more information

Presumably the joint probability mass function would inform you directly.

Your question is pretty much the same as asking “Given a random variable $X$, how do we calculate $P(X=x)$?” That is impossible to answer unless we know in advance what distribution $X$ has.
So, given a random vector $(X,Y)$, we can compute $P((X,Y)=(x,y))$ only if we know what distribution $(X,Y)$ has.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ be a probability space.
Suppose $X:\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a discrete random variable.
The probability mass function $p_X$ (of the random variable X) is then defined as:
$p_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ for $x \in$ Img$(X)$,
where $X=x$ is short for $\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)=x\}$.
If now $Y:\Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is another random variable (defined on the same space) one can define the joint probability mass function. What one does is to consider the tuple $(X,Y)$ as a "2-dimensional" random variable.
The probability mass function of $(X,Y)$,$p_{(X,Y)}$, is defined as follows:
$p_{X,Y}(x,y)=\mathbb{P}((X,Y)=(x,y))$ for $(x,y) \in$ Img$((X,Y))$, where $(X,Y)=(x,y)$ is a abbreviation of $\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)=x \wedge Y(w)=y \}$.
With the joint probability mass function $p_(X,Y)$ you can now calculate $P(X=x_1,Y=y_1)$.
Consider the following examples:
Example 1: ((fair) Coin toss)
Let us denote head as "$1$" and tails as "$0$". I.e. $X(Head)=1,X(Tail)=0$. Since we have a fair coin we get $p_X(0)=p_X(1)=1/2 $.
Now let $Y$ be the random variable associated with a second coin toss. Again we get $p_Y(0)=p_Y(1)=1/2.
Since the second coin toss is not influenced by the first one, we get $p_{(X,Y)}(0,0)=p_{(X,Y)}(0,1)=p_{(X,Y)}(1,0)=p_{(X,Y)}(1,1)=1/4$.
Example 2:
Let X be a random variable with values $-1,1$, with probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X=-1)=1/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(X=1)=1/2$.
Define the random variable $Y$ as follows:
$Y=1$ if $X=-1$ (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y=1)=1/2$),
$Y=-1$ if $X=1$ (i.e. $\mathbb{P}(Y=1)=1/2$)
Then we get the following "possible" values for $X$ and $Y$ (and thus the joint probability mass function $p_{(X,Y)})$
$\mathbb{P}(X=-1,Y=-1)$=0
$\mathbb{P}(X=-1,Y=1)$=1/2
$\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=-1)$=1/2
$\mathbb{P}(X=1,Y=1)$=0

In the first example you can now calculate $\mathbb{P}(X=x,Y=y)$ using $p_{(X,Y)}$ and compare it with $\mathbb{P}(X=x)\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$ to see that X,Y are independent.
In the second example you can do the same thing to see that X,Y are dependent random variables. (Which is very natural since our definition of $Y$ depends on the values of $X$).
